# ggplot geom_col giving unexpected results

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the code below, generates the graph as also shown below. I dont understand why there is just one thick bar covering February, I would have thought there would be just 2 bars at the correct locations of 5th January and 5th February. Any suggestions?

```
date<-c(as.Date("2021-01-05"),as.Date("2021-02-05"))
total<-c(1,5)
df<-data.frame(date,total,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df%>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(x= date,y=total))+
  scale_x_date(limits=c(as.Date('2021-01-01',"%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date('2021-04-01',"%Y-%m-%d")),date_breaks = "7 days")+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1)
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_col()` reparameterises the data as a rectangle given by the xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax points, dependent on the width of the bar. The default width assigned to your bars causes the xmin parameter to fall out-of-bounds on the x-axis. Because the handling of out-of-bounds values is done by `scales::oob_censor()`, these get replaced by `NA` and the bar disappears.

One option is to set the `oob` (out-of-bounds) handler to `oob_squish()`, which will replace out-of-bounds values with the nearest limits.

```r
library(ggplot2)

date<-c(as.Date("2021-01-05"),as.Date("2021-02-05"))
total<-c(1,5)
df<-data.frame(date,total,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_col(aes(x= date,y=total))+
  scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c('2021-01-01', '2021-04-01'), "%Y-%m-%d"),
               date_breaks = "7 days", oob = scales::oob_squish)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
```

[image]

A different option is to set the width of the bars such that the bars do not become out-of-bounds in the first place.

```r
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_col(aes(x= date,y=total), width = 1)+
  scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c('2021-01-01', '2021-04-01'), "%Y-%m-%d"),
               date_breaks = "7 days")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>